# Load testing an API in python for response time

Tags: python, api, load-testing

I would like to do a Load test over an API I developed. I have tried the Jmeter which seems to be only providing the elapsed time and the latency

So is there a way I can do the same test(i.e sending over 100 POST request to the API) using python so I can get much better control over it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write the response time by configuring what has to be written to the file, but it can be done by right clicking the Response Times over time graph(which has to installed via the plugins)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

JMeter provides whatever you "tell" it to provide, check out [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) documentation chapter to see what JMeter can store and what are the default values.

Once you have the results file with the metrics you want you can either analyze it yourself or generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) from it.

If you're good in Python development you might want to try [Locust](https://locust.io/) tool which is Python-based and the workload is defined via [locustfiles](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html) - Python scripts.

More information: [JMeter vs. Locust - Which One Should You Choose?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-vs-locust-which-one-should-you-choose)